# unable to use FeatureUnion in scikit-learn due to different dimensions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I'm trying to use `FeatureUnion` to extract different features from a datastructure, but it fails due to different dimensions: `ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions`

---

### Implementaion

My `FeatureUnion` is built the following way:

```
    features = FeatureUnion([
        ('f1', Pipeline([
            ('get', GetItemTransformer('f1')),
            ('transform', vectorizer_f1)
        ])),
        ('f2', Pipeline([
            ('get', GetItemTransformer('f2')),
            ('transform', vectorizer_f1)
        ]))
    ])
```

`GetItemTransformer` is used to get different parts of data out of the same structure. The Idea is described [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2034#issuecomment-25317009) in the scikit-learn issue-tracker.

The Structure itself is stored as `{'f1': data_f1, 'f2': data_f2}` where `data_f1` are different lists with different lengths.

---

### Question

Since the Y-Vector is different to the Data-Fields I assume that the error occurs, but how can I scale the vector to fit in both cases?

Comment: a short and ugly solution would be to concat ``data_f1`` and ``data_f2`` to the lenght of ``data_f2`` and set the length of the Y-Vector to ``data_f2``

Answer (score 7):

Here's what worked for me:

```
class ArrayCaster(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def fit(self, x, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, data):
    print data.shape
    print np.transpose(np.matrix(data)).shape
    return np.transpose(np.matrix(data))

FeatureUnion([('text', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='text')),
            ('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), binary=True, min_df=3)),
            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())
          ])
        ),

        ('other data', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='has_foriegn_char')),
            ('caster', ArrayCaster())
          ])
        )])
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this applies to your question, but we ran into the same error in a slightly different situation and just solved it.

Our `f1` entries were each lists of 15 numeric values and we needed to do tf-idf on `f2`.  This generated the same error about incompatible row dimensions.

After running it through the debugger, we found that the shapes of our matrices were subtly different going into the `hstack()` call in `FeatureUnion`:  `(2569,)` and `(2659, 706)`.

If we cast `f1` to a 2D numpy array, the shape changed to `(2659, 15)` and the `hstack` call works.

The cast was something like this: `f1 = np.array(list(f1))`.